# The below Facebook login php code shows unexpected error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am trying to use facebook login and echo the user's /me/ graph details. I wrote the following code as per facebook's developer page but something is wrong and the page https://qonnect.co/fbcon.php wont load !

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Qonnect | Your online ID on the web</title>
<meta content="online identity, social network, contact details, share, personal profile">
<?php require_once("facebook.php"); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <p>chekc access token at bottom</p>
<?php 

   $app_id = "353349231445***";
   $app_secret = "1299cd46fd******";
   $my_url = "https://www.qonnect.co";

   session_start();

   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty(code))
   {
    $_SESSION['state']= md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
      $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'] . "&scope=user_birthday,read_stream";

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

      //rechecking of sessions state variable for CSRF attack !
      if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] === $_REQUEST['state'])) {
        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"."client_id=".$app_id.
        "&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)."&client_secret=".$app_secret."&code=".$code; //code exchanged for access token.
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);

        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=". $params['access_token'];
        $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
        echo("Hello", $user->name);
     }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting on which line exactly?

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

See it for yourself: https://qonnect.co/fbcon.php

Comment: The web server's error log will contain a more detailed error message. Do you have access to it?

Comment: I am a novice. i do have access to it. its on a shared hosting ! Looking for one right away

Comment: [Sun Mar 03 06:04:33 2013] [error] [client 116.68.91.228] File does not exist: /home/gcrapu/public_html/qonnect.co/404.shtml
[Sun Mar 03 06:04:33 2013] [error] [client 116.68.91.228] File does not exist: /home/gcrapu/public_html/qonnect.co/favicon.ico

This is the error log from my cpanel.

Comment: Is there more? You need a different error than "file does not exist"

Comment: The two error lines are repeated for some 5 times and then are no other error logs. 
Weird isn't it.
If it helps. previously this fbcon.php page's content was there in the index.php. The same error happened so i contacted the hosting services, they said theres some problem in the line
if(empty(code))
She said she saw this error via some console !

Comment: Ok i digged in and found a hidden error log in my cpanel file manager.

It says this [03-Mar-2013 06:28:32 America/New_York] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /home/gcrapu/public_html/qonnect.co/fbcon.php on line 22

Comment: That looks like the ticket.

Comment: i didnt get that Pekka !

Comment: [01-Mar-2013 22:19:05 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BaseFacebook' not found in /home/gcrapu/public_html/qonnect.co/facebook.php on line 25

Answer (score 0):

> if i am right the  500 Internal Server Error may be a problem caused
>   by
>
> ```
> A malformed php cgi script
> An invalid directive in an .htaccess or other config file
> Limitation imposed by file system and server software 
> Error/Missing php.ini
> ```
>
> In most case it is an invalid .htaccess directive

can you check

1) .htaccess

2)let me know thr catching of the whole php code

```
>       try{
>     
>     } catch(Exception $o){
>           echo $o;
>       }
```

3.can you set a

```
set_time_limit ( int seconds)
```

Comment: In the process of finding my .htaccess on my shared hosting, i found this error log. It says this

[03-Mar-2013 06:28:32 America/New_York] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /home/gcrapu/public_html/qonnect.co/fbcon.php on line 22

And i couldnt find .htaccess ! Could that be a problem ?

Comment: [01-Mar-2013 22:19:05 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BaseFacebook' not found in /home/gcrapu/public_html/qonnect.co/facebook.php on line 25

Comment: hey find that  base_facebook.php  resides beside facebook.php

Comment: base_facebook.php is another file and it resides under the same directory as the facebook.php